# Saber si un DataGridViewCkeckboxCell está checkeado o no

Tags: c#, excepciones, checkbox, datagrid

Tengo un DataGridView en el cual su primera columna es del tipo DataGridViewCheckboxColumn.

Para crear esta columna lo hago así aunque ya he probado a hacerlo desde la parte de diseño de Sharpdevelop y me pasa lo mismo:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn CheckBoxColumn = new 
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
CheckBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Guardar";
dataGridView.Columns.Add(CheckBoxColumn);
dataGridView.Rows.Add(false);
dataGridView.Rows.Add(false);
dataGridView.Rows.Add(false);
dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.ColumnHeader;
dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

El problema viene en el momento que quiero consultar si el checkbox sobre el que hago click está checkeado o no.

Para comprobarlo he intentado lo siguiente en el método DataGridViewCellContentClick:

```
void DataGridViewCellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    bool isCellChecked = (bool)dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;

    if(isCellChecked)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Fila " + e.RowIndex + " seleccionada");
    }
}
```

El error me da en la línea en la que hago bool isCellChecked=...

Me lanza un NullReferenceException porque la propiedad Value es null, pero es null siempre, lo haya checkeado o no, no puedo comprobar de ninguna manera su valor.

Comment: Hay alguna instrucción más en el código que no nos hayas puesto? Yo estoy haciendo pruebas y siempre me devuelve valor copiando y pegando lo que nos muestras

Comment: No había ninguna otra instrucción, creo el datagridview desde el editor gráfico y lo único que hago es cargar su DataSource con un list. Lo que me "mosquea" es que cuando los creo le paso false y value me lo deja a null... Acabo de publicar una respuesta con la solución al menos a mi caso. Gracias @Marc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He encontrado la respuesta y lo que pasa es que tenía que activar el evento CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged para "confirmar" ese cambio de valor del checkbox. Tengo que hacer lo siguiente:

```
void DataGridViewCurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView.IsCurrentCellDirty)
        {
            dataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        }
    }
```

Si activas este evento y lo defines como lo acabo de poner, en el método DataGridViewCellContentClick ya puedes acceder al valor del checkbox, entonces quedaría:

```
void DataGridViewCurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView.IsCurrentCellDirty)
        {
            dataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
        }
    }

void DataGridViewCellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    bool isCellChecked = (bool)dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;

    if(isCellChecked)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Fila " + e.RowIndex + " seleccionada");
    }
}
```

Implementando estos dos métodos se soluciona.

Solución sacada de : http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.es/2010/04/datagridview-uso-del-checkbox.html

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Estaba buscando la solucion porque tenia el mismo problema, pero me dí cuenta de lo que podia ser y encontre la respuesta: El problema, es que si nunca se selecciono esa celda, sera siempre `null` (si la seleccionas y desceleccionas entonces quedara como `false`), lo que debes hacer y para ahorrarte colocar ese `evento`, es preguntar si la columna que vas a preguntar por su propiedad `check` es diferente a `null`. Aca te dejo mi solución:

```
        for (int Indice = 0; Indice <= dgvDatosUsuarios.Rows.GetLastRow(DataGridViewElementStates.Displayed); Indice++)
        {
            //Pregunto si la celda es diferente a null
            if (dgvDatosUsuarios.Rows[Indice].Cells[5].Value != null)
            {
                //Casteo el check del objeto a booleano y pregunto si es true
                if ((bool)dgvDatosUsuarios.Rows[Indice].Cells[5].Value)
                {
                    //Imprimo el contenido de alguna de mis celdas para comprobar que muestra solo las seleccionadas                
                    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(dgvDatosUsuarios.Rows[Indice].Cells[1].Value));
                }
            }
        }
```